# UINavigationBar with blur and no shadow image

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

The `UINavigationBar`’s documentation for the `shadowImage` property says:

> For a custom shadow image to be shown, a custom background image must also be set with the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method. If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless of the value of this property.

I want to remove the hairline (`shadowImage`) of the `UINavigationBar` while preserving the translucency effect. Other than using private APIs to find and hide the image, is there an ‘official’ work around?

I can’t see anything by Apple on how they achieved the same thing for the Safari iOS app so I was just wondering if anyone on here has a solution

Thanks

Comment: have you try setting to nil ```shadowImage```?

Comment: "If the default background image is used, then the default shadow image will be used regardless of the value of this property."

Comment: @AdamCarter The Safari iOS app _has_ the shadow, so what are you talking about there?

Comment: "Other than using private APIs to find and hide the image, is there an ‘official’ work around?" You already cited the "official" rules, so what actual question do you have? You know everything there is to know about this.

Comment: @matt To clarify, I mean that I would like to remove the shadow image of the navigation bar and keep its translucency, then underneath place a view which looks like it extends the navigation bar. This view would then imitate the shadow of the navigation bar to look like the view is part of the nav bar. In Apple’s docs they only describe doing this by removing the translucency of the nav bar, yet in Safari for iOS they preserve translucency

Comment: "I mean that I would like to remove the shadow image of the navigation bar and keep its translucency, then underneath place a view which looks like it extends the navigation bar" Demonstrated here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: So I ended up looping through the navigation bar’s subviews to look for an image view whose image is equal to the shadow image

Comment: @AdamCarter Yes, we used to have to do that with UIToolbar when its shadow was broken. But I'm a little worried that directly accessing the shadow image view might not fly in an app submitted to the App Store (though I have no direct knowledge on the matter)...

Answer (score 0):

To hide shadow below UINavigationBar:
Put this code snippet, it is in Swift. Anyway it work for me. 
Hope this will help other who seek for the answer.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let img = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = img
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    }
```

more detail you can find out in this linked bellow:
https://medium.com/simple-swift-programming-tips/how-to-disable-uinavigationbar-shadow-in-ios-9-swift-2bdf6e9be41e#.sqmrtn8pq